# How to calculate $\operatorname{Var}(b_0)$ where $b_0$ is estimator for $\beta_0$ in $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Consider the equation $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$ for $i=1, \dotsc, n$.

We have unbiased estimators $b_0$ and $b_1$ for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ respectively, where $b_0=\bar{y}-b_1\bar{x}$ and $b_1= S_{xy} / S_{xx}$.
One can easily show that
$$
    \operatorname{Var}(b_1)
  = \operatorname{Var}\left( \frac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}} \right)
  = \frac{1}{S_{xx}^2} \operatorname{Var}(S_{xy})
  = \frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}.
$$

Now, I'm trying to find $\operatorname{Var}(b_0)$ as follows:
$$
    \operatorname{Var}(b_0)
  = \operatorname{Var}(\bar{y}) - \operatorname{Var}(b_1\bar{x})
  = \operatorname{Var}(\bar{y})-\bar{x}^2 \operatorname{Var}(b_1)
  = \operatorname{Var}(\bar{y})-\frac{\bar{x}^2\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}.
$$
Now,
$$
    \operatorname{Var}(\bar{y})
  = \operatorname{Var}\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum y_i \right)
  = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum \operatorname{Var}(y_i)
  = \frac{\sigma^2n}{n^2}
  = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \operatorname{Var}(b_0)
  = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}-\frac{\bar{x}^2\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}.
$$

But according to the answer given in my book, it says
$$
    \operatorname{Var}(b_0)
  = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{\bar{x}\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}.
$$

Note:
$$
 S_{xy} = \sum{x_i(y_i-\bar{y})},
 \qquad
 S_{xx} = \sum{x_i(x_i-\bar{x})}.
$$

Comment: $\operatorname{Var}(aX + bY) = a^2 \operatorname{Var}(X) + b^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y)$. What is $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The problematic part is

> $\operatorname{Var}(b_0)   = \operatorname{Var}(\bar{y}) -
>  \operatorname{Var}(b_1\bar{x})$

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are random variables with finite variances then the variance of the difference is

$Var(U-V)=Var(U)\color{red}+Var(V)-2Cov(U,V)$

If $U$ and $V$ are additionally independent then $Cov(U,V)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
var(b_0) = var( \bar{y} ) + var(b_1 \bar{x} ) - 2cov(\bar{y} , b_1 \bar{x} ), 
$$
where 
$$
cov(\bar{y} , b_1 \bar{x} ) = \bar{x}cov\left( \bar{y}, b_1\right) = 0,
$$
as
\begin{align}
cov(\bar{y}, b_1) &= \frac{1}{nS_{xx}}cov\left(\sum y_i , \sum ( x_j - \bar{x})y_j \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{nS_{xx}}\sum ( x_j - \bar{x})\sigma ^ 2 \\
& = \frac{\sigma ^ 2 ( \bar{x}- \bar{x})}{nS_{xx}}\\
& = 0.
\end{align}
Hence, 
$$
var(b_0) = var( \bar{y} ) + var(b_1 \bar{x} ) = \frac{\sigma ^ 2}{n} + \frac{\sigma^2 \bar{x} ^ 2}{ S_{xx}}, 
$$

Comment: It should be $var(b_0) = var( \bar{y} ) + var(b_1 \bar{x} ) - 2cov(\bar{y} , b_1 \bar{x} )$

Comment: @Jan Thanks. Edited. Pls remove the downvote. The answer is 100$\%$ correct now.

Comment: @V.Vancak Thanks! I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine ;)